# face error when trying to render my code with redux part . dispatch a string from a file but not getting it on app.js

Tags: redux, react-redux

**REDUX RENDERING ERROR**
face error when trying to render my code with the redux part. Successfully dispatch a string from a file but not getting it on app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Home from './components/home'
import Data from './components/data'
import Nav from './components/nav'

import './App.css';


function App(props) {
  const  data  = this.props.data //error in this line
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Nav />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/data' component={Data} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return {
      data : state.data
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined.        


> 12 |   const  {data}  = this.props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using functional component, so you have to get `props` direct without `this`

```
const data = props.data
```